# Calculate relative frequency, mean abundance when present and mean total abundance of species

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset of the abundance of 37 plant species in 1415 quadrats.

Example:

```
Quadrat <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
Species1 <- c(23, 41, 32, 58, 0)
Species2 <- c(1, 5, 0, 0, 20)
Species3 <- c(80, 90, 75, 58, 65)
df <- data.frame(Quadrat, Species1, Species2, Species3)
```

How can I easily calculate and compute a nice table presenting:

- Relative frequency for each species (number of quadrat where the species is present / total number of quadrats)
- Mean abundance for each species when present (0 should be considered as NA) PLUS the standard error of this mean
- Total mean abundance for each species (0 should be considered as 0) PLUS the standard error of this mean

I have been losing my time in Excel, and I am sure it is possible to do it in R. Thank you!

Comment: Check out ``dplyr::group_by``, ``dplyr::summarise`` and ``flextable``

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to do it:

- Relative frequency

  library(spaa)
  rel.freq = freq.calc(df)*100
- Mean abundance for each species when present (0 should be considered as NA) PLUS the standard error of this mean

  df[df == 0] <- NA
  cover.present = colMeans(df, na.rm = T)
  mf <- function(x){sd(df[,x])/sqrt(length(df[,x]))}
  cover.present.SE = sapply(df,function(x) sd(x, na.rm = T)/sqrt(length(na.omit(x))))
- Total mean abundance for each species (0 should be considered as 0) PLUS the standard error of this mean

  total.cover = colMeans(df)
  total.cover.SE = sapply(df,function(x)sd(x)/sqrt(length(x)))